# ipwatchd detects non-existing conflict?

Tags: arp

Ipwatchd is telling me about a conflict that I just do not understand. As far as I can tell, there is no conflict. Am I reading the message wrong?

It's a Xen machine with the following network interfaces:

- bridge 'eth0' (00:25:90:06:db:1c), containing peth0 (00:25:90:06:db:1c, same address): 89.188.x.y
- eth1 (00:25:90:06:db:1d): 10.0.0.2

The fact that the bridge is called `eth0` and the physical Ethernet is `peth0` is a Xen 4.0 idiosyncrasy.

The ipwatchd message is:

```
MAC address 0:25:90:6:db:1c causes IP conflict with address 10.0.0.2 set on interface eth1 - passive mode - reply not sent
```

The MAC mentioned is that of eth0 (peth0). The 10.0.0.2 address is of 00:25:90:06:db:1d. 00:25:90:06:db:1c doesn't have 10.0.0.2 and is not conflicting.

So, what does the message mean?

Ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:06:db:1c  
          inet addr:89.188.x.y  Bcast:89.188.x.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe06:db1c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58247406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23023834 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:56204502250 (52.3 GiB)  TX bytes:3110101143 (2.8 GiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:06:db:1d  
          inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe06:db1d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:385178792 errors:0 dropped:487 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:119369439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:440434537631 (410.1 GiB)  TX bytes:13541159915 (12.6 GiB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:fb6e0000-fb700000 

peth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:06:db:1c  
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe06:db1c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:218781801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:250404109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:88855286807 (82.7 GiB)  TX bytes:258263353372 (240.5 GiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fb5e0000-fb600000
```

brctl show:

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
eth0            8000.00259006db1c       no              peth0
                                                        vif1.0
                                                        vif10.0
                                                        vif11.0
                                                        vif13.0
                                                        vif14.0
                                                        vif15.0
                                                        vif19.0
                                                        vif2.0
                                                        vif22.0
                                                        vif3.0
                                                        vif4.0
                                                        vif5.0
                                                        vif6.0
                                                        vif7.0
                                                        vif8.0
```